# leer una columna especifica desde un txt con javascript

Tags: javascript, txt

hay forma de realizar una tabla en html pero que levante los datos desde un txt?
Yo tengo un excel donde tengo una tabla dinámica, y sumo valores según un argumento x, se puede hacer lo mismo con js y html?? No quiero subir a un servidor la información, quiero solo poder hacerlo en mi pc levantando datos siempre del mismo txt.- Es posible ? o tengo que seguir con excel?[image: Tabla Dinamica Excel]
En la imagen muestro lo que hago en excel  con una tabla dinamica, es decir, tomo los datos de una hoja y filtro lo que necesito saber , en este caso me muestra el EStado y la suma total de todas las filas que contienen el mismo estado, el txt donde tengo los datos tiene bastante columnas y filas, pero yo necesito estas que estan en este orden.
Lo que trato de averiguar es se puede hacer lo mismo en html con js, sin otra herramienta porque recién estoy en proceso de comprender estas herramientas.
En excel y openoficce lo puedo hacer, pero a veces el programa se vuelve muy lento y no tengo una buena maquina y supuse que talvez en html era mas liviano...
gracias por asesorarme

Comment: Nadie te impide abrir el fichero y parsearlo como quieras, usando por ejemplo un [Filereader](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: si tienes excel seria mas facil que lo cargues directo, con esto  [exceljs](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs)